# Code after function executing before function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

At least I think that is what's happening. I have code in a .js file that calls a function existing in another .js file.  This function makes an ajax call to a php page that creates and returns a list of radio buttons with one selected.  When the function returns, code gets executed that passes the value of the selected radio button to a php page and generates some more lists (again via ajax).  Every time the user changes the selected radio button, the lists get updated.  This works when I select them via clicking, however, when the page loads, the proper radio button is selected, but the code to capture the selected radio button returns undefined.  When I place an alert directly after the function call it works properly.  This leads me to believe things are executing out of order.

The way I worked around this before was to place the code after the first function call in a function and call that function at the end of the first function.  However, this doesn't help with my understanding of why this is happening.  Here is the code:

First file:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#add_page",function(){
     restore_addreg_page();
     //alert('function finished');
     var selected_group = $('#group :checked').val();
}
```

Second file:

```
function restore_addreg_page(){
    get_major_groups();
        ...more code
}
function get_major_groups(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'PHP_Scripts/get_major_groups.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        $('#major_groups').empty();
        $('#major_groups').append(data);
        $('#major_groups').trigger('create');
        $('input:radio').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id") == 'major_group0'){
                $(this).prop("checked",true).checkboxradio('refresh');
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('Query Error');
    }
});
}
```

If I uncomment the alert, everything works correctly otherwise selected_group is undefined and the calls after that depend on that fail.

Comment: AJAX: _Asynchronous_ JavaScript and XML. I suspect there are many answers to this exact same question all over SO.

Comment: use `$("#major_groups input[type=radio]")` instead.

Comment: @AspiringAqib I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to select just the radio buttons based in some container.  Is there a good, comprehensive source for discussing jquery selectors?  I know $(#id), but I'm not familiar with more specific ones like above.

Comment: Dumb question, sorry.  Googled 'jquery selectors' and found it

Comment: well, you can see jQuery API for jQuery selectors but you may only end at the above one which i have given. It will select all radio buttons in the #major_groups div by using it with each() otherwise if you wanna bind some event to all radios then you can by on(). Your one was also good but i did like to go with my one. and see this for demos : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your function gets returned before it gets result. By default ajax() call is async call. To make it sync, set async property to false in ajax() as shown.

```
$.ajax({
...........
async: false,
..............
```

Comment: Would another way be to wrap the code following the function in a function and call that function in the success function of the ajax call?